# Calculo de Sobra VISUALG

Tags: visualg, portugol, divisão

Boa noite, Colegas!

Estou com esse problema e não consigo encontrar uma solução inclusive na documentação da IDE. Gostaria de saber qual comando usar para Pegar a sobra de uma divisão para utilizar-la nas instruções abaixo dela. Sei basicamente que o comando é MOD OU % só não sei como usar isso dentro da formula.

```
var
```

N,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7: INTEIRO

inicio

```
  Leia(N)
  N2 <- N/100 % 100
  Escreval (N2)
  Escreval //Quero usar a sobra da divisão aqui em baixo para outra conta, imaginando que o valor da variável N1 é 576
```

fimalgoritmo

Comment: N2 <- N % 100 atribuirá à variável N2 o resto da divisão de N por 100. O que você fez não tem muito sentido.

Comment: Então pensando muito aqui, ficou sem sentido! Porém consegui fazer colocar na resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ficou assim:

```
algoritmo "EXERCICIO 18"
```

var
N,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8: INTEIRO

inicio

```
  Leia(N)
  N2 <- N % 100
  ESCREVAL (N/100 MOD 100," nota(s)", " de", " R$ ", "100,00")
  N3 <- N2 % 50
  ESCREVAL (N2/50 MOD 50," nota(s)", " de", " R$ ", "50,00")
  N4 <- N3 % 20
  ESCREVAL (N3/20 MOD 20," nota(s)", " de", " R$ ", "20,00")
  N5 <- N4 % 10
  ESCREVAL (N4/10 MOD 10," nota(s)", " de", " R$ ", "10,00")
  N6 <- N5 % 5
  ESCREVAL (N5/5 MOD 5," nota(s)", " de", " R$ ", "5,00")
  N7 <- N6 % 2
  ESCREVAL (N6/2 MOD 2," nota(s)", " de", " R$ ", "2,00")
  N8 <- N7 % 1
  ESCREVAL (N7/1," nota(s)", " de", " R$ ", "1,00")
```

fimalgoritmo

Comment: Creio que você deva dar uma estudada no significado do operador resto da divisão (MOD ou %).